# Primefaces Ajax calling Javascript

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I was wondering if you could call javascript inside of an ajax statment specificlly I am trying to get the following to work.

```
        <p:commandLink id="saveButton" value="Save" >
            <p:ajax event="click" actionListener="#{bean.saveButtonPressed()}" />
            <p:ajax event="click" actionListener="if(#{cbean.showSaveOverlay}){saveOverlay.show();}" />
        </p:commandLink>
```

And showSaveOverly gets set inside saveButtonPressed.

Any idea how I would do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the PrimeFaces-provided [`RequestContext`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/requestContext.xhtml) API.

First normalize your ajax listener:

```
<p:ajax event="click" listener="#{cbean.showSaveOverlay}" />
```

Then add the script to `RequestContext#getScriptsToExecute()` in the action listener method accordingly:

```
public void showSaveOverlay() {
    if (...) {
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().getScriptsToExecute().add("saveOverlay.show()");
    }
}
```

If you're not on PrimeFaces 7.0 yet, then use `RequestContext#execute()` instead:

```
public void showSaveOverlay() {
    if (...) {
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("saveOverlay.show()");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no actionListener in p:ajax. I have the last version of the PrimeFaces 6.3

Comment: it could be a good idea and great help to say how and where to define saveOverlay as a javaScript code.

Comment: @Mazy JavaScript code is normally defined in a JavaScript file.

Comment: and how to call it? JS/file/adress/name.function() ? and if in the same package is with name.function() ?

Comment: @Mazy: not related to JSF. Start here http://www.htmldog.com/guides/javascript/beginner